# Difference between pinax.apps.accounts, idios profiles, and django.auth.User

Tags: python, django, pinax

What's the difference between pinax.apps.accounts and the idios profiles app that were installed with the profiles base project?

As I understand it, the contrib.auth should be just for authentication purpose (i.e. username and password), and the existence of User.names and User.email in the auth model is historical and those fields shouldn't be used; but the distinction between accounts and profiles are lost to me. Why is there pinax.apps.account and idios?

Answer (score 3):

The Pinax account is just a wrapper for that holds the user, timezone and language. user is a foreign key relation to the standard django.auth User model.

```
class Account(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True, verbose_name=_('user'))
    timezone = TimeZoneField(_('timezone'))
    language = models.CharField(_('language'), max_length=10, choices=settings.LANGUAGES, default=settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

The idios Profile model basically does the same thing but has some custom methods:

```
class ProfileBase(models.Model):
    # @@@ could be unique=True if subclasses don't inherit a concrete base class
    # @@@ need to look at this more
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name=_("user"))

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("profile")
        verbose_name_plural = _("profiles")
        abstract = True

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        if idios.settings.MULTIPLE_PROFILES:
            # @@@ using PK here is kind of ugly. the alternative is to
            # generate a unique slug for each profile, which is tricky
            kwargs = {
                "profile_slug": self.profile_slug,
                "pk": self.pk
            }
        else:
            if idios.settings.USE_USERNAME:
                kwargs = {"username": self.user.username}
            else:
                kwargs = {"pk": self.pk}
        return reverse("profile_detail", kwargs=kwargs)

    @classmethod
    def get_form(cls):
        return get_profile_form(cls)

    def _default_profile_slug(cls):
        return cls._meta.module_name

    profile_slug = ClassProperty(classmethod(_default_profile_slug))
```

Neither of them replicates the authentication functionality of django.auth.User if that is what you are asking. It doesn't look like either one has a dependency on the other either. So if you can't see a good use for both of them, just go with the one that makes sense.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that since ProfileBase is an abstract model, you'll have to write your own subclass. This is a good thing, since you'll almost undoubtedly want to add fields to store user info.

Comment: Apart from having different fields, why has there been a need to have a separate pinax.Account model, that seems to replicate the purpose of profiles. I can see the value of separating auth from profiles (it allows alternative auth scheme, and allows a single user to own multiple profiles), but there doesn't seem to be any advantage of separating accounts and profiles?

Comment: Specifically, why did accounts not inherit from ProfileBase.

Comment: Because profiles is built on top of Pinax right? Only way you could make accounts inherit from ProfileBase would be to fork the code from Pinax and release a different build. Maybe I am missing something though.

Comment: @thomallen: Pinax 'basic' project installed idios as requirements, and setup an project-level app that uses 'idios' for profile management.

Comment: @thomallen: ... and then they also added pinax.apps.accounts separately. My question is that why Pinax is setting up projects with both pinax.apps.accounts and idios, where neither seems to be aware of each other, and their functionality seems to be similar with each other. That seems redundant to me, unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1):

Profiles are meant to be used for public data, or data you'd share with other people and is also more descriptive in nature.

Account data are more like settings for you account that drive certain behavior (language or timezone settings) that are private to you and that control how various aspects of the site (or other apps) function.