# Customizing Profile Model in Pinax: Integrity error in admin when OnetoOneField is added

Tags: django-models, django-admin, pinax

I'm new to Pinax and Django. I'm trying to extend the Pinax Profile model by having a OneToOneField that pulls from another application I plugged in (in this case, django-swingtime : http://code.google.com/p/django-swingtime/). I've got all of my models to show up in the django admin interface, but I cannot add new Users (which I want to do in the process of adding new Profiles). I get the following error:

```
IntegrityError at /admin/auth/user/add/

profiles_profile.event_type_id may not be NULL

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/admin/auth/user/add/
Django Version:     1.3.1
Exception Type:     IntegrityError
Exception Value:    

profiles_profile.event_type_id may not be NULL
```

My Pinax version is 0.9a2. EventType is a model from django-swingtime. I get this error when I'm trying to add a User from anywhere within the Django admin.

Here's the my Profiles/models.py (changed lines have comments next to them)

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

from idios.models import ProfileBase

from swingtime.models import EventType #ADDED HERE

class Profile(ProfileBase):
    name = models.CharField(_("name"), max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    about = models.TextField(_("about"), null=True, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(_("location"), max_length=40, null=True, blank=True)
    website = models.URLField(_("website"), null=True, blank=True, verify_exists=False)
    event_type = models.OneToOneField(EventType) #ADDED HERE

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "Name: %s -- %s" % (self.name, self.about) #ADDED HERE
```

Perhaps if someone could explain the relationship between accounts, profiles, and users and what files are OK to edit and which ones are inadvisable to edit (for instance, I don't think I want to be changing anything around in my Pinax site packages...), I can make some progress. Also, I assume this idios plugin is involved in the process, but the link to documentation I've found will load (http://oss.eldarion.com/idios/docs/0.1/).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my error, though I'm interested in other answers and additional information since some of this is speculation/still unclear to me. I think the error stems from Pinax accounts automatically creating a "blank" idios profile for every new user created (speculation). Since I had said every profile must have a OneToOne foreign field associated with it and had not allowed for this OneToOne field to be null, there was a problem.

This question describes some of the differences between the idios profile app, Pinax account and the standard django User accounts:

[Difference between pinax.apps.accounts, idios profiles, and django.auth.User](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11601907/difference-between-pinax-apps-accounts-idios-profiles-and-django-auth-user)

What I did to solve this problem was using the Django's signalling capabilities to make sure that as soon as a Profile is generated, so is an instance of the foreign field. This is described here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/signals/

Make sure to read the bit about double signalling, since this has caused trouble for some other people:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/signals/#preventing-duplicate-signals

The final modification to my code that got rid of the error was this. Note that besides adding signalling I also explicitly said that the OnetoOneField was allowed to be null.

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from idios.models import ProfileBase
from swingtime.models import EventType

#for signals
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

class Profile(ProfileBase):
    name = models.CharField(_("name"), max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    about = models.TextField(_("about"), null=True, blank=True)
    event_type = models.OneToOneField(EventType, null=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return "Name: %s -- %s" % (self.name, self.about)

def create_User_EventType(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    print "checking creation of profile"
    if created:
        print "User event type is being created"
        event_label = "%s_hours" % (instance.name)
        print "the event label is" + event_label
        EventType.objects.create(abbr=instance.name,label=event_label)

post_save.connect(create_User_EventType,sender=Profile,dispatch_uid="event_post_save_for_profile")
```